# Caratheodory's theorem and outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inequality

I'm trying to show that $$\lambda(A)=\lambda(A\cap E)+\lambda(A\cap E^c)$$ where $\lambda$ is an outer measure, $A\subset \mathbb{R}$, $E \subset \mathbb{R}$, and $E$ is an elementary set; that is, $E$ is a union of finitely many bounded intervals.

By countable subadditivty, I know $$\lambda(A)\le\lambda(A\cap E)+\lambda(A\cap E^c)$$ since $A=(A\cap E)\cup (A\cap E^c)$. I need help showing the opposite inequality.

Answer (score 2):

By the definition of Lebesgue outer measure, for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists open set $O$ with $O \supset A$ such that $\lambda (O) \leq \lambda (A) +\epsilon$. Now Observe that 
$$\lambda (A) +\epsilon \geq \lambda (O) = \lambda (O\cap E) + \lambda (O\cap E^c) \geq \lambda (A\cap E) + \lambda (A\cap E^c),$$
the equality above comes from that the Lebesgue outer measure is countably (and finite) additive for Lebesgue measurable sets.

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we have 
$$\lambda (A) \geq \lambda (A\cap E) + \lambda (A\cap E^c).$$